# master detail form with two or more lists

Tags: 2013

I want to create a new form to edit surveys (I have thought about two lists surveys and questions, a survey can have many questions) and I want it to be editable so user can add or delete questions to a survey, how can I achiveve this with infopaht 2013 or sharepoint designer 2013 or any other way?

Comment: I posted on something I did which may be useful to you:

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140095/how-can-lists-be-made-to-support-master-detail-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, or solutions:

you can use a nustache template that can render html + jquery, as part of this html you can put your detail list as elements and with jquery you can open a new window to edit the detail items

Answer (score 0):

I would follow a different approach. Firstly I would agree with other relevant groups about the format of the survey and than upload it. 
You can create a new document (it can be word, excel, access etc ) and allow every user to edit the document at the same time. You can use versions to leave out updates that you don't find useful. If at the end everyone agrees with the content and structure of survey, you can use the survey app provided in Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: Excuse me but I didn't want to make surveys, I have two linked lists and I named them survey and questions but are not sharepoint surveys.